Нужна ли запятая в данной части текста?
В предложении «Не знаю единственная ли я такая, но(,) прошу учитывать, что меня нет в той группе, и меня так же интересует ДЗ по выше сказанным предметам» в части «но(,) прошу учитывать, что меня…» нужна ли запятая после части с «но»?

В этом предложении есть проблемы не только с запятыми. Но если уже говорить о запятых, то почему вас не заинтересовала постановка запятой после "Не знаю"?

После редактирования:
Не знаю, единственная ли я такая, но прошу учесть, что меня нет в той группе и что меня также интересует ДЗ по названным выше предметам.
Пояснение
Предложение сложное, 5 предикативных основ.
Не знаю (что?) — главное,
единственная ли я такая — придаточное изъяснительное,
но прошу учесть (что?) — главное,
что меня нет в той группе и (что) меня также интересует ДЗ по названным выше предметам — два однородных изъяснительных придаточных, союз И, нет запятой.
